# fadeIn() on a tr cause display:block - bug?

Tags: jquery

If you try to do a `.fadeIn()` on a `<tr>` in jQuery, it adds (on Firefox and IE7) the element `display:block;`. (on IE7 also zoom:1).

I'm using the version 1.5 of jQuery. Is it a bug? And how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much to work with in your question.

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/AG34Z/) (using 1.5.2) shows that the display is `table-cell` after the `.fadeIn()`.

*code from example*

```
$('tr')
    .hide()
    .delay(1000)
    .fadeIn( 1000, function(){alert($(this).css('display'));} );
```

***BUT***

If your CSS has something like this:

```
tr {
    display:none;
}
```

Then jQuery won't know what to set the display as, and will just assume `block`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/AG34Z/1/

If that's the case, then don't set the `tr` to `display:none`, but instead give a class, and set the display on that.

```
.myrow {
    display:none;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/AG34Z/3/

You can see that the `.fadeIn()` now sets the correct `display` on the row.

Comment: Uhm...yes is the example you say! I have the display:none on the <tr>. So how can I do? remove the class .myrow after the fadeIn()?

Comment: @markzzz: If you just do the `.fadeIn()`, it will work. jQuery will see that it is a `tr` element, and it will construct a new `<tr>` element for the purposes of testing to see what its display should be, and it will use that. Then it will store that result using `jQuery.data()` for future reference. You could also remove the class in the callback after the `fadeIn()`. That certainly is an option too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `fadeTo`, or `animate` over `fadeIn`

http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/
http://api.jquery.com/animate/